# Error messages when deploying a web application in Weblogic 12.1.3

Tags: web, deployment, web-applications, weblogic12c

We are trying to deploy our application's .war file in Weblogic 12.1.3 but we get the following error messages:

```
Task 156 initiated: [Deployer:149026]deploy application sarp on sarp.
Task 156 failed: [Deployer:149026]deploy application sarp on sarp.
Target state: deploy failed on Server sarp
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassInfoImpl.<init>(ClassInfoImpl.java:41)
        at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.polulateOneClassInfo(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:240)
        at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.populateClassInfos(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:193)
        at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.<init>(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:44)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.War.initializeClassInfosIfNecessary(War.java:446)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.War.getAnnotatedClasses(War.java:376)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebBaseModuleExtensionContext.getAnnotatedClasses(WebBaseModuleExtensionContext.java:63)
        at weblogic.j2ee.managedbean.ManagedBeanModuleExtensionFactory.create(ManagedBeanModuleExtensionFactory.java:65)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.createModuleExtensions(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:264)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.initDrivenObjectArray(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:232)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:107)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
        at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:40)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Why are we getting this error? Any Suggestions?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

This error is because the version of JDK from your WLS is lower than bytecode is being deployed in your war file.

please check JDK of your WebLogic and your war file.

Weblogic 12.1.3 can use 7 or 8.

EDIT1: log4j2 is an example that has bundled bytecode of Java9 that, when is deployed in WebLogic 12.1.3 an exception is thrown (`com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>`). The newest version (without modification) that can be deployed directly in WLS 12.1.3 is log4j 2.8.2.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but versions in Weblogic and in the war file are the same: 
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)

Comment: Does the war file have jar under WEB-INF/lib?
all the classes inside have bytecode for 8?. for example, do you have log4j2 inside?

Comment: Our WEB-INF/lib includes a lot of jar files. For example, we have log4j-api-2.9.0.jar,  log4j-core-2.9.0.jar and log4j-jcl-2.9.0.jar